# deno postgres.js embeddings query in deno under supabase functions

Tags: postgresql, deno, openai-api, supabase-database

Trying to run an embeddings query on data stored from openAI. Currently using Supabase functions, using the following library. Any ideas on how to fix this?

OpenAI Embeddings response is successful -

```
const [{ embedding }] = embeddingResponse.data.data;
const query_embedding = embedding;
```

```
import postgres from 'https://deno.land/x/postgresjs/mod.js'


const res = await sql`
select
id,
content,
  1 - (documents.embedding <=> ${query_embedding}) as similarity
from documents
where 1 - (documents.embedding <=> ${query_embedding}) > ${similarity_threshold}
order by documents.embedding <=> ${query_embedding}
limit ${match_count}
```

`;

On execution, the following error returns. Please note, pg_vector extension has already been enabled an i'm able to save embeddings successfully -

```
Error... PostgresError: malformed vector literal: "0.0013529072,-0.01248068,-0.021260735,-0.009094394,-0.0059045693,0.04160703,-0.028719138,-0.018231653,-0.005847417,-0.0039685275,0.02343253,0.020260567,-0.0124663925,-0.009144402,-0.013738035,0.028161902,0.02916207,0.00086130627,0.010994715,-0.015588349,0.00782275,-0.0022450222,0.003548814,-0.024804192,-0.009637343,0.008608597,0.015702654,-0.033634257,-0.01856028,-0.027047427,0.032262594,0.006036734,-0.012052037,-0.0009858808,-0.019074652,-0.006551107,0.00666184,0.0058259843,0.021789396,0.020774938,-0.0035988223,0.006126035,0.013023629,0.031205272,-0.011916299,0.014002366,-0.020103397,-0.05046567,-0.0022110878,0.019017499,0.035948932,0.0016172376,0.016074145,0.005100862,0.0026808102,0.017088601,0.0016190236,-0.0064903824,-0.005561654,-0.000671542,0.027804699,0.0044936165,-0.016774263,0.023303937,0.0015582991,0.01573123,0.016902857,-0.008672894,0.0055973744,-0.012752155,0.025447156,0.015245433,-0.010523207,-0.022275193,0.023089616,-0.006783289,-0.042778656,0.00006451983,-0.012730722,0.010273164,-0.004147129,-0.011473367,0.021475058,0.009851664,-0.010101707,-0.0142952725,0.016202739,0.010051698,-0.010808969,-0.00961591,0.022803852,0.026518766,0.006436802,0.009687351,0.0027969012,-0.004782951,-0.026447326,0.018574568,0.002771897,-0.0052651754,-0.0076298607,-0.007937055,-0.006904738,-0.0023039607,-0.022289481,-0.018303093,-0.018688872,0.008122801,0.022546668,-0.021089278,-0.013216519,0.042435743,-0.00572954,-0.02237521,-0.020560617,-0.015102552,-0.00805136,0.0033041297,-0.0024039776,-0.026604496,0.012845027,0.0044936165,0.013016486,-0.033348493,0.008322835,0.015702654,-0.046379264,-0.011787706,-0.018874617,0.0034845173,0.076241456,0.017817296,0.02176082,0.0035005915,-0.0016243816,0.050151333,-0.012930756,-0.0032130429,-0.0128164515,-0.023546835,0.004125697,0.010901842,0.0049186884,0.013273671,-0.01856028,0.015602636,0.040635437,0.0076227165,-0.020274855,-0.014459586,0.009865953,-0.0024986365,0.040121064,-0.019631889,0.0039042311,-0.019674754,-0.046436418,0.0013707674
```

Schema definition is as following -

```
create table documents (
  id bigserial primary key,
  content text,
  embedding vector (1536)
);
```

#supabase #deno #openai #postgresjs

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it working. See working version below, ended up using "JSON.stringify".

```
  const res = await sql`
    select
    id,
    content,
      1 - (documents.embedding <=> ${JSON.stringify(query_embedding)}) as similarity
    from documents
    where 1 - (documents.embedding <=> ${JSON.stringify(query_embedding)}) > ${similarity_threshold}
    order by documents.embedding <=> ${JSON.stringify(query_embedding)}
    limit ${match_count}
  `;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `[]` around your vector values.

```
import postgres from 'https://deno.land/x/postgresjs/mod.js'


const res = await sql`
select
id,
content,
  1 - (documents.embedding <=> [${query_embedding}]) as similarity
from documents
where 1 - (documents.embedding <=> [${query_embedding}]) > ${similarity_threshold}
order by documents.embedding <=> [${query_embedding}]
limit ${match_count}
`;
```

Comment: The reason why the example in [this](https://supabase.com/blog/openai-embeddings-postgres-vector) Supabase blog article does not need brackets around the embeddings is because the embedding argument that is passed has a type of vector, so SLQ knows it's a vector, where as in your case, you are just passing it as raw string, so you have add any necessary things to format it correctly.

Comment: The "query_embedding" parameter already gets passed as an array. At first i thought it was due to the missing quotes and tried the following, but no dice. 

```
const query = query_embedding.map(i => i.toString());
```

Comment: also tried the following ${query_string}::vector and no luck.